# Handlebars template with JSON data and accessing arrays and objects

Tags: arrays, json, templates, recursion, handlebars.js

I am learning handlebars and JSON, so this may be an easy answer for some. 
I have a json file (basically a representation of  nested folders.), included below.

I am having trouble understanding how to get the path of all the folders and subfolders into my handlebars template. I have tried `{{each .}}`, `{{#each folders}}`, etc. but I either just get the top folder or nothing. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Handlebars:

```
<ul>
    {{#each folders}}
        <li>{{path}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "path": "json",
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "folder-top",
            "folders": [
                {
                    "path": "subfolder1",
                    "folders": [
                        {
                            "path": "sub-subfolder1",
                            "folders": [
                                {
                                    "path": "sub-sub-folder",
                                    "counters": {
                                        "total": 1,
                                        "images": 1,
                                        "files": 1
                                     },
                                     "name": "sub-sub-folder"
                                 }
                             ],
                             "counters": {
                                 "total": 2,
                                 "images": 1,
                                 "folders": 1,
                                 "files": 1
                             },
                             "name": "sub-subfolder1"
                         }
                     ],
                     "counters": {
                         "total": 2,
                         "images": 1,
                         "folders": 1,
                         "files": 1
                     },
                     "name": "subfolder1"
                 }
             ],
             "counters": {
                 "total": 2,
                 "images": 1,
                 "folders": 1,
                 "files": 1
             },
             "name": "folder-top"
         }
     ],
     "counters": {
         "total": 2,
         "images": 1,
         "folders": 1,
         "files": 1
     },
     "name": "json"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is *not* easily solved because, as @Jojo has stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41186063/3397771), you need to do an `{{#each}}` over an unknown number of nested folders. The crux of your question is: how to *recursively* apply a Handlebars template?

In order to achieve our recursion, we will need to call a chunk of template from *within* our template; and keep calling that chunk for as long as we have child folders to render. Handlebars has [partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html), which serve as reusable chunks of template to be called from other templates. So let's create a partial for piece of template that is to be applied to each folder:

```
<script id="RecursiveFolderPartial" type="text/template">
    <li>
        {{path}}
        {{#if folders}}
            <ul>
                {{#each folders}}
                    {{> recursiveFolder this}}
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
</script>
```

Note that our partial calls a partial, `recursiveFolder`. The crucial part is that we will make sure to register our partial with the name, `recursiveFolder`, that way, our partial will *recursively* call itself.

Now that we have moved most of the template markup to the partial, the only job for our template is to get our partial recursing by making the first call to the partial with the root folder object as context:

```
<script id="Template" type="text/template">
    <ul>
        {{> recursiveFolder this}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

All that is left for us to is to correctly wire-up our template and partial and we should be ready to go.

```
var raw_template = document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML;
var raw_partial = document.getElementById('RecursiveFolderPartial').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);

Handlebars.registerPartial('recursiveFolder', raw_partial);
```

I have created a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/L5y4u7cb/).

**Update:**

If you wish to render the full path to the current folder - that is, the current folder path appended to its parent folder's paths and delimited with a "/" - then you will need to concatenate the current path onto the previous path and to pass the result to the partial call.

Let's begin by creating a Handlebars helper to concatenate strings:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join('');
});
```

Next, we will update our partial template to make use of a [parameter](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#partial-parameters) that we will call `previousPath`. Our partial will output the result of concating `previousPath` "/" and the current `path`. We will also use the result of this concatenation to be the `previousPath` parameter to the recurisve calls of the partial:

```
<li>
    {{concat previousPath '/' path}}
    {{#if folders}}
        <ul>
            {{#each folders}}
                {{> recursiveFolder this previousPath=(concat ../previousPath '/' ../path)}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/if}}
</li>
```

We should also update our template to start the `previousPath` parameter to an empty string:

```
<ul>
    {{> recursiveFolder this previousPath=''}}
</ul>
```

An new fiddle with this implementation can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/kzjbzvq0/).

Comment: Thanks! This is great and I would never have figured it out! One question, is there a straightforward way to write the full path to a folder using this? e.g _folder-top/sub-folder1/sub-subfolder1_. I tried `{{../path}}/{{path}}` but no go.

Comment: Working with your code I have learned a bit about partials. Thanks. One thing I am struggling with is how to get only the name of the containing folder of each folder. I would really appreciate any direction on how to integrate this. My brain is getting recursive!

Comment: @Macsupport: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/kzjbzvq0/2/) what you're looking for?

Comment: That is very helpful. I think I can work with that code. Thanks for the extra effort to make the jsfiddle!

Comment: Using your code I am almost successful. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/w4z7vz9m/). One last question ( You can ignore if I am being a pest!) is how to ignore the containingFolderName of the root folder.

Comment: @Macsupport: What do you mean by "ignore" it?

Comment: Sorry, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702172/how-to-exclude-an-array-object-element-with-handlebars) explains what I am trying to do and [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/tp9w87bu/) shows that I got it to work using that helper. Now I need to get the image paths to match the folder paths.

Comment: Your solution is very confusing and has a lot of needless complexity. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vmy5p6j2/) is an example of a better approach.

Comment: Story of my life, needless complexity and confusion! Appreciate your help and going above and beyond. A sincere thanks and I learned a lot as well!

Comment: @7684 Taking a look at this answer recently, I came up with a question. In your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vmy5p6j2/), how could one get the name "json" in  the RecursiveFolderPartial script , `{{#unless (is name 'json')}}`, from the actual json data name value `"name": "json",`, so one wouldn't have to type the name in the RecursiveFolderPartial, it could just get it from the json file.

Comment: @Macsupport: If I understand what you mean, you would just need to pass the `name` value from the root object to through each recursive call, just as is being done for `previousPath` and `containingFolderName`. Here is an example using "rootName" as the variable name: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vmy5p6j2/8/

Comment: Thanks for answering!  in the line `{{#if (is ../path 'json')}}`, It seems I  could use `{{#if (is ../path ../rootName)}}`?

Comment: @Macsupport: Yes. That's right. https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vmy5p6j2/10/

Answer (score 1):

You actually iterate only over the first dimension of the Object. So either, if you know how many dimensions your object have, try something like:

```
{{#each folders}}
  {{#each folders}}
    {{#each folders}}
      {{#each folders}}
         ...
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Or you try to setup the Object in just one dimension.

Anyhow i have no clue how to itarate over n dimensions of an object.